# Does PSD file format save path data?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I've been trying to decide on a file format to save a multitude of "master" images for a game project. The final product will be vector images. I would like to have the master copies of the images saved in a format that saves layers and all other important pieces of data for editor-side modifications later if needed.

I've been trying to decide between the PSD format or Illustrator's AI format. The most important fact I need to know about the PSD format here that I don't already know to make an informed decision is whether the PSD format saves path data. If it does is there any reason that would make it inferior to the AI format in regards to the manner in which it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not Photoshop saves path data can be somewhat irrelevant. Photoshop will retain the vector data within the PSB, PSD, PDF, and EPS formats (*Please* see the links below).

However, you **can't** output straight path data from Photoshop in any* format. i.e. Photoshop does **not** save or export vector *files*, it saves raster files with embedded vector data, unlike Illustrator - which will do the inverse given raster content is present in Illustrator.

- [How to create vector graphics In Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop)
- [Is a Photoshop EPS file a vector format?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/is-a-photoshop-eps-file-a-vector-format)
- [Can Photoshop be used for vector purposes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96/can-photoshop-be-used-for-vector-purposes)
- [Extract vector graphics from PDF in photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56987/extract-vector-graphics-from-pdf-in-photoshop)

For my money, I'd **much, much** rather have an AI file with embedded raster images. *Non-layered* raster images can be extracted from Illustrator easily at their existing quality. *Layered* raster files may be another matter and may require a 2 file backup to retain everything in a workable state.

*One caveat is **SVG**. Photoshop *can* output straight vector in SVG format. However, if artwork is too complex SVG may not be a viable solution. And for backup purposes I'm not certain I'd trust the SVG format to remain viable. But for simple, flat shapes, SVG *may* be an option for output -- but if that's the construction, I can't see why Photoshop would be more beneficial than Illustrator.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! It is a very common misconception indeed. What threw me off was the fact that you see tools for manipulating path data in Photoshop.

Comment: @Hawkeye4040 the reality is for most general output, print or web, it's typically not a *critical* aspect for many. However, it becomes *exceptionally* critical when considering further editing or output which *requires* the complete absence of raster data. There's *always* raster data with *any* Photoshop file format (except the SVG caveat above).

Comment: Yeah with the information provided I think Illustrator is certainly the go-to. It'll allow me to output to SVG or more accurately the custom format I've made for games (programming is more my area). AI would certainly be the format as I want to export the path data to my format as you would SVG.

Comment: @Hawkeye4040 AI may be a a bad format since its undocumented! So to be future proof you rely on adobe to future proof your files.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why it may be a bad format?

Comment: I'd be a little upset to have to make my own format for that as well at this early stage but I'd certainly do it if truly needed.